# tool-tip shows on hover via js, but not in css

Tags: css, tooltip, game-development

trying to toggle the visibility of some simple span using css, it doesnt appear to be working. When written in js the event works fine. What's the issue?

```
document.getElementById('theme-tooltip').style.display = 'none'
document.getElementById('theme-btn').onmouseover = function(){
    document.getElementById('theme-tooltip').style.display = 'block'
}
document.getElementById('theme-btn').onmouseout = function(){
    document.getElementById('theme-tooltip').style.display = 'none'
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id = 'startpanel'></div>
<span id = 'theme-tooltip'>tooltip</span>
<div class="icon-bar">
    <a id='theme-btn'><i class="fas fa-palette"></i></a> 
    <a id='hotkeys-btn'><i class="fas fa-keyboard"></i></a>
    <a id='settings-btn'><i class="fas fa-cog"></i></a>
    <a id='changelog-btn'><i class="fas fa-book"></i></a>
    <a id='discord-btn'><i class="fab fa-discord"></i></a>
</div>
```

```css
#theme-tooltip{
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
}
#theme-tooltip:after{
    content: ' ';
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:10px solid #000;
    border-right:10px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: -40%;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
#theme-btn:hover #theme-tooltip{
    display: block;
}
```

theme-tooltip will display whenever the mouse is hovered over the theme-btn.

Comment: Post your html code too...

Comment: You can apply css to previus sibling in css!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have written the selector `#theme-btn:hover #theme-tooltip` assumes that your tooltip is inside the #theme-btn element, which is not the case.

Are you trying to show the same tooltip for each icon, or will you have a different one for each icon? If you need a different tooltip for each icon, I would put the tooltip element after each  tag. You also want to wrap each of these icon-tooltip pairs in a container, so that you can correctly position each tooltip:

```
<div class="icon-wrapper">
    <a id='theme-btn'><i class="fas fa-palette"></i></a> 
    <span id = 'theme-tooltip'>tooltip</span>
</div>
```

and your css with look like this:

```
.icon-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
#theme-tooltip{
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: -100px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 22px;
    text-align: center; 
    display: none;
}
#theme-tooltip:after{
    content: ' ';
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:10px solid #000;
    border-right:10px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: -40%;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
#theme-btn:hover + #theme-tooltip{
    display: block;
}
```

Note that the `position:relative;` on the icon-wrapper is for your tooltip's absolute position to be relative to the icon-wrapper.

Comment: i had the hover element appending to the wrong element, thanks.